# For loop causes page to crash

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loops

Index.php

```
<?php
    require_once("inc/db.php");
    require_once("inc/map.php");

    $db = new Database();
    $map = new Map($_POST['x'], $_POST['y']);
    $map->createMap();
    $map->battle();
    $map->move();
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Db.php

```
<?php
    class Database{
        private $config;
        protected $sql;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->Connect();
        }

        public function Connect(){
            $this->config  = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
            $con = $this->config;
            $this->sql = new PDO("mysql:host={$con['host']}; dbname={$con['dbname']}",
            $con['username'],$con['password']);
            $this->sql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
?>
```

Map.php

```
<?php 
    class Map extends Database{

      public $x;
      public $y;
      public $width = 5;
      public $height = 5;

      public function __construct($x,$y){
            $this->x = $x;
            $this->y = $y;
      }

      public function createMap(){
          for($x=0; $x < $this->width; $x++){
              for($y=0; $y < $this->height; $y++){
                  Database::Connect();
                  echo "<div id='map'>";
                  echo "<div class='map_columns' title='{$x}_{$y}' data-x='{$x}' data-y='{$y}' id='{$x}_{$y}'>";
                  $this->spawnPlayers($x,$y);
                  echo "</div>";
              }
              echo "<div class=\"break\"></div>";
          }
      }

      public function spawnPlayers($x,$y){
          $stmt = $this->sql->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE x = "'.$x.'" AND y = "'.$y.'"');
          $stmt->execute();
          while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              echo "<img title='{$rows['name']} \n {$rows['x']}|{$rows['y']}'>";
          }
      }

      public function battle(){
          $stmt = $this->sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM user GROUP BY x,y HAVING count(*) > 1");
          $stmt->execute();
          $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if($rows){
              echo "<input type='submit' id='battle-btn' value='Fight'>";
          } else{
          }
       }

       public function move(){
         if(isset($this->x) && isset($this->y)){
            $stmt = $this->sql->prepare("UPDATE user SET x = '$this->x', y = '$this->y' WHERE name = 'Wiz'");
            $stmt->execute();
         }
       }
    }
?>
```

Index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".map_columns", function(){
        var x = $(this).attr("data-x");
        var y = $(this).attr("data-y");
        $.post('./index.php', {x: x, y: y}, function(){

        });
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        $("#map").load("./index.php");
    }, 1000);
});
```

So I made a map using for loops and the data being outputted is the user coordinates.  Wherever I press on the map, it will update the users coordinates to that location.  This works as intended but I have an issue. I need the map to auto refresh / update when a users coordinates have been updated.

So my approach was to use .load() in ajax as I use in most projects but the difference here is the for loop.  I'm assuming because it reinterates the for loop a second time, it causes everything to crash. How can I solve this problem? I know games have done the same but I can't think of a counter-solution.  The code written is pretty understandable.

I re-wrote the original version so it's clean and understandable for stackoverflow, the original looks as below:

https://i.gyazo.com/a34793a0af0344b867f0537830da5cd3.mp4

It's being auto updated using the html  which isn't viable.  So please how can I update the div with new information(players axis) without the page crashing?

Comment: Why are you creating a new database connection for every single iteration of your loop? And you're calling connect statically when it's an instance method

Comment: @MarkBaker It's not intended but I need to initiate the database somewhere

Comment: Yes, initiate it once, using `$this->Connect()` before your loops, or even in the constructor

Comment: The problem is that you're loading the entire page into a DIV, not just replacing the contents of that DIV.

Comment: Or just call the `parent::__construct()` in your `Map` class constructor

Comment: It's also reloading `Index.js`, so you're duplicating everything that it does.

Comment: testing what you guys wrote

Comment: `$db = new Database();` in your `index.php` is a meaningless additional database connection.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be crashing anymore, thank you. I have another question though.  When two players are on the same div, a fight button appears.  How can I make it so the button appears at the same time for both users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're loading the entire page into the `#map` DIV, but you just want to replace its own contents. Change it to:

```
    $.get("index.php", function(response) {
        $("#map").replaceWith($(response).find("#map"));
    });
```

It would probably be better to create a new script that just returns what you want, instead of using `index.php` and then ignore all the other contents.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, do you by chance know how I can make it so the button to fight would appear at the same time for both people.  Currently the first person to go to another player will see "Fight" first.  I need to make it so it loads right after? If not, it's fine; I will find a solution

Comment: Synchronizing scripts between different clients is complicated, I'm not sure how you would do it.